# Resources NotFoundException

Tags: android, proguard

I trying to build release version of apk and get error when launching on Honor 5x (api 23):

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
File res/color/abc_hint_foreground_material_light.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f0d01e7
```

At the same time app doesnt crash on emulator (api 25).
I've tried to add this to proguard rules but it didn't help:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
       public static <fields>;
}
```

Build type:

```
release {
            shrinkResources true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
        }
```

I use android studio 3.0 canary 1, suport library 25.3.1, build tools 25.0.2 and firebase-ui 1.2.0

Please, help me find a solution for this issue.

Comment: try this : gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: I've updated jdk to 131 and executed 'gradlew assembleRelease'. It finished without errors, but the issue remains.

Comment: Setting shrinkResources to 'false' worked for now...

Comment: Are you using Iconics and google_material_typeface library? I believe its related - I get that error too. No solution yet... :(

Comment: No, I don't use these libraries

Answer (score 3):

I am facing similar problems when using "shrinkResources true".

Later I got help with reference to this section
[Customize which resources to keep](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-resources).

> If there are specific resources you wish to keep or discard, create an
>   XML file in your project with a  tag and specify each
>   resource to keep in the tools:keep attribute and each resource to
>   discard in the tools:discard attribute. Both attributes accept a
>   comma-separated list of resource names. You can use the asterisk
>   character as a wild card.

Add a whitelist to the "keep.xml" file in the path "res/raw/",
used to reserve resources that were lost due to "shrinkResources true".

For example "res/raw/keep.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*"
    tools:discard="@layout/unused2" />
```